# Catching alerts

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to be able to stop alerts from showing. And when Alert.show is called, I want to be able to get the message and stop the Alert from showing.

I would really apreciate if somebody has an idea of how this could be done.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  You seem to be talking about general error handling - what Alerts are you talking about?

Comment: _I am talking about the Alert class. I don't want to reenvent it neither I want to extend the class or make my own class. But if I am using someone else code and this person made a mistake in calling the Alert class instead of sending me an event. I want to be able to stop his alerts. I though of using the PopUpManager. I don't know but if someone has any clues then...Thanks_